# React Native: Recording console.log output into JSON to be sent to server

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, logging, console

Sorry if this is noob question, I simply couldn't find an answer to this specific question.

I'm building a react native app and very new to this as well, my project manager asked me if I can add features that allows app to keep track of what's user doing in my app.

I stumbled upon many solutions including `google analytics` libs available to react native developers, but I just can't understand it quite well yet. Then I thought about using a simple `console.log` and just recording it to a `JSON` file, but same problem, can't really wrap my head around it and can't find a good source to learn from.

Can anyone give me pointers as to how can I record my `console.log` output into a `JSON` so that I can send it to server at the end of each session?

I basically need a starting point and clear directions if possible :)

Comment: It's a bad practice to track your users with `console.log` .. i would recommend to dig deeper into `google analytics` and use that.

Comment: You can use this: https://github.com/corymsmith/react-native-fabric 
read the `Answers` section.

Comment: @oma I'm looking into that right now, thanks :)

Comment: @MRFrhn Thanks for the suggestion, I'll look into that :)